# OKTA Authorization Code Flow with PKCE using Angular SPA

Tags: angular, authentication, openid-connect, okta, pkce

I am trying to implement authentication in Angular using okta as IAM. I want to implement Authorization code flow with PKCE as implicit flow poses security vulnerabilities exposing the access code and id token in the address bar. Can someone help me with the implementation example?

Comment: I'd recommend starting with https://developer.okta.com/code/angular/ which has mutliple samples and guides. The libraries now use PKCE by default to avoid the problems with the implicit flow you mention.

Was there a particular part of the implementation you were struggling with?

Comment: When creating a client app in OKTA org in order for PKCE to work do I select allowed grant type to be Authorization code or implicit or both?

Allowed grant types 
Client acting on behalf of a user

Authorization Code    CHECK

Implicit      CHECK

Allow ID Token with implicit grant type     CHECK

Allow Access Token with implicit grant type      CHECK

is this a valid setting?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options to see an Angular example with auth code flow + PKCE quickly:

1. Use the [Okta CLI](https://cli.okta.com) and run `okta start angular`. [Here's a video](https://youtu.be/aMmTcLnoZzc) that shows how this works.
2. Create a new app with the Okta CLI, then run `ng add @oktadev/schematics`.
3. Clone and run the [Okta Angular samples](https://github.com/okta/samples-js-angular).

Comment: I was referring to this example. https://github.com/okta/samples-js-angular/tree/master/custom-login
Here they have used okay sign in widget  and okta angular sdk but the flow doesn't involve generation of challenge code to exchange it along with authorisation code for access and id tokens through a POST request.

Comment: Also,
I was reading through Aarons Parecki's blog post https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/01/is-the-oauth-implicit-flow-dead
Here he has shown a way to implement auth code flow with PKCE  using plain javascript and has followed the flow that I mentioned before (generating code challenge)

Does all of this happen in the background with the current version of okta angular sdk? and would it be the same when using okta signin widget?

Comment: Yes, the Okta Angular SDK and Sign-In Widget handle the code challenge and all the PKCE stuff for you. Both depend on Auth JS, which enables PKCE by default. https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js

Comment: Thanks Matt! That eases up my life so much.